# What are the steps for creating level in Libgdx with Box2d?

Tags: libgdx, game-design, box2d, assets

I have been trying to learn game programming for a week, although I have a good knowledge of programming.

I don't understand some steps of game design. I'm recently working to clone the [iSlash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duellogames.islash&hl=tr) game.I'm so confused about creating level like this one.

For example , this is a level of this game.

[image: Image Link]

This crab or whatelse must be designed in tools like photoshop, am I right? There are objects which can move around, but inside this crab so I think, I can use Box2D.

Here is my temporary design this game.[image: Mine].
I want to use a my own object and move balls inside this object,but the problem is here.I can't imagine that how I should do this? If I use mesh like below code,

```
mesh.setVertices(new float[] { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
                                        0.5f, -0.5f, 0,
                                        0, 0.5f, 0 });
```

I think , It's very very hard way to create a level and I don't know what my object's coordinate.It takes forever.

In brief, What should I do? What tools should I use? How do big games like Angry Bird or above game (iSlash) solve this? Can I use tiled map editor for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Level designer is a full time job.**

Using an editor is really **mandatory** if you don't want to lose a lot of time. Most professional games like angry birds probably have teams that develops dedicated custom tools to ease their level designers job.

**Tiled :**

If i remember well, with Tiled Editor you can place shapes and manually set properties to them. You could use the xml output from tiled and write a custom loader to instantiate your physic objects with this data, it will faster and cleaner than to hardcode your objects in your code but i don't think this would be the most productive way to do it.

**Box 2D editors :**

There is several editors dedicated to create Box 2D game levels. I don't know them well enough to recommend one, but, if you google "Box2d Editor" or "Box2D Level Design tool", you should find plenty of them. Search for one that is easy to use & that can output a file format that you can easily parse with libgdx (json or xml).

So here is what i found :

**[1 - RUBE :](https://www.iforce2d.net/rube/#)**

Seems like a really complete level design tool. Not free though, but affordable. So i'd recommend to test the trial and see if you can easily use the output for your libgdx game.

[image]

**[2 - Physics Editor :](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/features)**

I also found this other **tool**, seems interesting and complete. 
However it's doesn't seem to be free either, but there is a free trial.

[image]

**[3 - Physics Body Editor :](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/)**

Here is also an interesting free tool to create box 2d shapes that even come with a loader for libgdx. It doesn't seem to be a complete level design tool, but i would try it if i were you, hopefully it will still work with the current libgdx version:

[image]

Comment: Here is working Physics Body Editor library https://gist.github.com/grulg/8691e7ee7709367ce165 and editor itself https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/downloads/detail?name=physics-body-editor-2.9.1.zip&can=2&q= .